# regexp for filtering URLs with blacklisted domains

Tags: regex, url, filtering

I am trying to create a regexp that could match all valid URL's but wouldn't match some of domains listed as "black list" domain

I found many examples with [whitelisting domains](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/117316.aspx) or using "doesn't contain" operator **(?!blacklist)** but none of them is working for my case with "doesn't contain" domains.

**Edit with answer**:
(thanks to Mephiztopheles), for filtering all urls except 3 example domains:

```
(?:https?:\/\/).(?:(?!example\.com|youtube\.com|testdomain\.co\.uk).)*$
```

example for testing: http://regexr.com/3at84

Comment: What language are you using, which regex syntax? Can you supply an example of what should be filtered and what not? Have you tried: `(?!((http:\/\/)?www)?\.example\.com).*`?

Comment: I think this will make me create a module / service to match a string for blacklist :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to swith some and remove some :)
Is this what you are searching for?

```
(?:https?:\/\/).(?:(?!example\.com).)*$
```

```js
$('body').append("https://www.example.com/test".match(/(?:https?:\/\/).(?:(?!example\.com).)*$/));
$('body').append("<br>");
$('body').append("https://www.examle.com/test".match(/(?:https?:\/\/).(?:(?!example\.com).)*$/));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works! Great. Thank you Mephiztopheles :)
Exactly what I needed! I will update my post according to your snippet.